# Setting maxage(0) to cookie in HTTPServlet doPost() and redirecting doesn't work

Tags: java, http, cookies

I'm doing something very simple that's just not working.

I have an html page with a button that's supposed to logoff and delete the login cookie, when pressed, it /runs this code in a servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
    deleteCookie(req, resp);

    resp.sendRedirect("login");

}

private void deleteCookie(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();

    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {

            if (CID_KEY_NAME.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0); // Should make the browser delete the cookie
                cookie.setValue(null);
                resp.addCookie(cookie);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `sendRedirect("login")` sends me to a new servlet that's responsible for the log-in but when I arrive at the new servlet and check for the existence of the cookie above, I can see it exists with the maxage value of -1

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for IE was that I should have set the Path for both setting the cookie and removing it.

Chrome is ok with having no path.

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTTP Cookies: What's the difference between Max-age and Expires?](http://mrcoles.com/blog/cookies-max-age-vs-expires/), at least Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 do not support `Max-Age`, but *do* support `Expires`. If this is your problem, then I would try setting both of those as:

> **Q. What if I set both expires and max-age in a cookie?**
>
> A. Every browser that supports max-age will ignore the expires regardless of it’s value, and likewise, Internet Explorer will ignore the max-age and just use expires.

That page also has a link to a [cookie persistence test page](http://mrcoles.com/media/test/cookies-max-age-vs-expires.html) which you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I can't verify it since I don't see how to define the 'expire' option in Java Cookie (javax.servlet.http.Cookie).

Comment: You could use a tool like Live HTTP Headers, Firebug's Net panel, or the like (in Firefox) to grab the entire HTTP exchange. While that won't help you set the value, it will tell you what exact cookie values are being exchanged, which may provide a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: You are right about the Expires tag but I found the real problem and it was that I didn't set the path.
I guess Java knows to set the correct attribute itself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ben on the finding, That was a really good catch. I have been trying to solve this for a couple of hours now.

Honestly It was quite easy to not notice the solution provided under the Comments section, Hence re-sharing the solution here for people like me :)

"The real problem and it was that I didn't set the path"

Modified Code Snippet:

```
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {

            if (CID_KEY_NAME.equals(cookie.getName())) {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0); // Should make the browser delete the cookie
                cookie.setValue(null);
                cookie.setPath("/"); // Set the Path value according to your code
                resp.addCookie(cookie);
                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Again, Thanks Ben!